# Get list of all Catalog Price rules using API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, catalog-price-rules, magento2-api

I want API endpoints that give me all available catalog price rules in Magento 2.
[image]

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/codelinks/attributes.html#RuleRepositoryInterface

Comment: @Aaditya It gives Cart Price Rules but i want Catalog Price Rules. Please see screen shots.

Comment: I think there's no endpoint for that one

Comment: Hello @Divyarajsinh While searching I got to know that although there is an API to handle shopping cart price rules, there is none to handle catalog price rules. And In product details API Check /V1/products/{sku} rest api is not working as well for Catalog rule applied price should come in special_price.

Comment: @Divyarajsinh Have you got any solution for this ? Or do you created any custom API for this ?

Comment: @Aaditya I don't get any solution. I am working on the custom API module.

Answer (score 0):

did you check magento docoument ? it lists all available API's and end points :

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html

And Sales Rules endpoints are :

> GET    /V1/salesRules/:ruleId
>
> GET    /V1/salesRules/search

Comment: I know these endpoints. It gives Cart Price Rules but i want Catalog Price Rules. Please see screen shots.